# Jenkins slave loses connection on date change

Tags: windows, jenkins, virtual-machine

When I change the date/time on the Windows VM that hosts a Jenkins slave, the slave will lose connection for a minute and then regain connection.  These are the commands I'm running in a command window.

```
date 11/03/13
time 00:00:00.00
```

This is needed for testing purposes. The problem just started happening recently.  I can execute the date/time change for Spring DST and it has no problems.

```
date 03/09/14
time 00:00:00.00
```

I've tried wrapping it with stopping/starting the time service but it still loses connection upon the date change.

```
net stop w32time
date 11/03/13
time 00:00:00.00
net start w32time
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with turning the time back. Just imagine you get your next credit card bill with last years date on it. You would probably try to call the credit card company to check if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem likely that "preventive node monitoring" is taking the slave offline due to clock difference. The nodes configuration page at `https://jenkins/computer/configure` is where you set this. Here's a screenshot:

http://note.io/1cr5JI4

When the slave loses connection, there should be an offline reason given on that node's page on the master. That reason should say something about time difference if that's the problem, or give you some other information if Jenkins itself took the slave offline.

If Jenkins is taking the slave offline due to clock difference, you could disable that function by un-checking the box.